# How do I give out an invite on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

When Careers first launched, [I purchased a 3-year spot](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker).  Now that Careers 2.0 is launched, we're able to 'invite' others into Careers. I have a high Stack Overflow reputation and I bought into careers, so I'm assuming I have invites waiting for me to give out. Where and how do I give out those invites?

Comment: How do I receive one? :-)

Comment: Hey, you got a job out of it, and now you want invites?  ;-D

Comment: I also wanna know how I can list my top questions/answers like Joel has in his profile.

Comment: @jjnguy I haven't seen that either. That's definitely worth its own question.

Comment: @George, I think they didn't have a chance to polish everything up before they went live.  I was gonna give it a day before I reported any more bugs.

Comment: @jjnguy & @george - the adding of your top answers is working now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [jjnguy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2598/jjnguy) figured out, the whole thing was a bit rushed at the end because of the LAUNCH conference.  Invites are working, but nobody has them yet while we iron out the other bugs (wouldn't want you to invite your friends to a buggy site!).  We'll start rolling them out in the next few days.

Once you have invites, they will show up in the menu on the profile page, right above the messages link.

**Update**

Invites are now being given out normally.  If you don't have invites to give out yet, it may be because your profile is not complete enough.

Comment: Is this working now? Still got no invite button afaict...

Comment: @bananakata yes, see my updated answer -- your profile may not be complete enough

Comment: Ok, how complete does it need to be? And perhaps this should be on the FAQ?