# Where are my Careers 2.0 invites?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I wanted to invite someone to Careers 2.0, but I can't find my invites anywhere on my profile page:

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/0.48046400%201302126787.png

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80408/how-do-i-give-out-an-invite-on-careers/80422#80422) answer, they should be "in the menu on the profile page, right above the messages link" - but I don't see them anywhere.

Comment: They are indeed between "public view" and "messages" for me.  Obviously I couldn't possibly say why you don't have any...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not everybody who signs up gets invitations.  Invitations are granted based on several criteria, one of which is how complete your profile is.  Based on your screenshot, your profile is not very filled out, which is probably why you have not received any invitations to give out.